# 74HC595 getting really hot on my pcb

Tags: schematics, expander

I've designed a fairly simple circuit with some shift registers (3 output en 1 input).

In the circuit, I've connected the inputs from the input shift register to pin connectors on the board (so I connect a NO switch and pull the pin to ground when pressed).

The pin from the shift register is also connect to V+ with a 10K resistor in between.

I've added the schematics from which I had a PCB made.

The issue is that, when a button is closed or the corresponding pin is grounded (in the schematics, one of Switch 1-8 connected to a 74HC165D), the first 74HC595 quickly heats up and eventually burns out.

Nothing else is connected at this point , only 5v and ground and the 5 wires from the arduino (the second power-port and 'chain' ports are meant to chain the board together). As a test I simply put a wire from a 'Switch Port' to Ground.

I'm a real beginner and always take on projects that are a little over my head...
I would really appreciate if someone can tell me about the mistakes I made designing this circuit.

[image: schematic]

This is the resulting PCB (created in EasyEDA)
[image]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason for that in the schematic. Show us the PCB. I'm a little concerned that you're drawing 10 mA or more from each of the '595 outputs -- are you switching on a bunch of LEDs as a result of pushing the button?

Comment: Only one LED per pin will be connected and the inputs will only be passed to a raspberry pi that's connected over I2C to the arduino who has it's digital pins wired to the PCB

Comment: There are many ŕeasons. No bypass caps on supply pins. Floating inputs. What is the control bus voltage levels and what is the HC595 supply voltage?

Comment: You say only one LED per pin, but there are 8 output pins on the '595, each trying to source about 15mA to an LED. If only one LED is lit at a time there's no problem. But if multiple pins are on then that's more current than the HC595 is designed for an it will heat up. There are plenty of LEDs that are plenty bright at just 5mA or even less. Use those and increase your series resistor accordingly (to the 500-1000 Ohm range).

Answer (score 6):

Unless there is some kind of hidden short, which would not show up on the schematic, you’ve  probably got a damaged ‘595, which could have happened from ESD, a supply transient or something like that. Something caused latchup then the excessive supply current destroyed the chip.

You really MUST have bypass capacitors on this kind of circuit. One 1uF for each 595 and at least 100nF on the  ‘165, for example. Also, from the half of the layout we can see it’s pretty horrific in terms of potential ground bounce and supply transients. You potentially have hundreds of mA switching in nanoseconds. A mostly solid ground plane and bypass caps would greatly help.

I would also suggest adding 1K resistors in series with the logic connections to and from the Arduino.

And, as @Justme notes in a comment, **all** inputs whether for parts of the chip that are used or not must be tied to a valid logic level, either directly or through a resistor (the latter gives you a bit more flexibility).

Comment: Do you mean the PCB layout that resulted from the schematics ? How can I change this for the better ?

Comment: A mostly solid ground plane, ceramic bypass capacitors near Vcc to ground plane on each chip and shorter fatter power traces.

Comment: Not to mention, no floating CMOS inputs on HC595. Connect the SRCLR to supply voltage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I've read some documentation about decoupling caps and added them to the circuit according to your suggestion. Would you mind explaining why the resistor on the inputs would give more flexibility ?

Comment: The resistors are useful if the ground of your board bounces below ground of the Arduino due to rapidly changing current + inductance. They prevent a large amount of current from flowing if it goes more than a diode drop below ground which can damage the chips. You’ll see this method used in situations such as serially addressable LED strips, as well as many non-hobbyist applications.

Answer (score 1):

The HC595 [datasheets](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC74HC595-D.PDF) usually only specify a total current of up to 75 mA (table "Maximum Ratings").

I suppose you're trying to drive each channel there with 10 mA. That will not really work well; even if you don't have all LEDs on at the same time, when reading the datasheet you'll extrapolate that at 5V supply, and drawing more than 6 mA from Q_A or Q_B, .. Q_H, your output voltage would drop significantly below 4 V. You'll probably would want to simulate how much current actually flows through your LED.

However, that's not (yet) what goes wrong here.

Considering your lack of decoupling caps, and your insufficient ground layout, what I find most likely is that the ringing from your buttons violently pulls around either ground or VCC (or both), and as a result, your first shift register (which has the most "floating" data input) sees clock and latch pulses where there are none, tries to switch its output, in turn pulls on VCC/loads Ground, and goes into a chaotic oscillation, wasting a lot of energy.

You could try whether adding decoupling caps suffices; do a new board spin, either way, with a ground plane, plenty of decoupling caps. Depending on what drives the circuit, you might also want to add weak pull downs on the data lines coming in from the outside, so that in the case that nothing is connected, they don't float.

Comment: Not sure why you get a negative rating, this explanation tells me a little bit more what's wrong with the board, although I don't really understand what decoupling caps are.
As for the LED's, could I use a transistor as a switch that's controlled by the HC595 ?

Comment: @oneindelijk Decoupling caps are the capacitors you typically find right at each power pin pair (supply and ground) of each IC with a generic value 100nF unless datasheet suggests otherwise. It is really hard not to notice them on circuit boards, now that you know what they are. Sure, you can drive the LEDs via transistors or buffers. Or, if you use better LEDs that light up brightly enough at lower currents, that would also be an option, so if you can find LEDs that are bright enough at 4mA for example.